# DHCP3-server not working correctly

Tags: apt, services, dhcp, dhcpd

I installed `dhcpe-server` with `apt-get install dhcp3-server`, and I want to configure it on terminal. When i type `dhcp` i just see these :

`dhclient dhclient-script dhcpd dhcpx`

I tried to start its service but I cant because it was not in service too . 
Now I don't know what can I do.

I write its config and save it in this directory: `/etc/dhcpd/dhcp3.conf`
and now I want to execute this command but I cant :

`dhcp3-server -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid at0`

said command not found. 
also when I go to `/var/run/` I cant see `dhclient-eth0.pid`  !

Comment: So your problem is you want to start that. But you can not? I am understart?

Comment: yeah , i install it , but it is not anywhere not in var/run nor service

Comment: service isc-dhcp-server restart 
[FAIL] Stopping ISC DHCP server: dhcpd failed!
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!
 then dhcp3-server replace by isc-dhcp-server ? yeah ? and if i want to use it i must type isc-dhcp-server ? i test it ; this command not found too

Comment: you should fisrt start that :) after that you can restart service or you can stop that. So you should first inter sudo service isc-dhcp-server start

Comment: i found answer !

Comment: first of all , dhcp3-server repalce with isc-dhcp-server i think all know that except me :D

Comment: this is answer dhcp3-server replace by isc-dhcp-server  
so i must execute this :
dhcpd! -cf /etc/dhcpd/dhcpd.cof  -pf /var/run/dhcp.pid at0 
and if anyone use ad-hoc like me in its configure it is not supported anymore u must replace it with interim; and if you want to start or restart service use this :
isc-dhcp-server start/stop/restart => /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start/stop/restart
this is answer tnq everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/isc-dhcp-server

use these commands:

If you want to **start** service:

```
 sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
```

If you want to **restart** service:

```
sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

If you want to **stop** service:

```
 sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop
```

tips:

1.Also `dhcp` command by itself does not start that. That is a service not a program to run.

2.you should first start any service before stop or restart

---

about second part of your question. Remember when you type `apt-get install dhcp3-server` on the terminal . You get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'isc-dhcp-server' instead of 'dhcp3-server'
isc-dhcp-server is already the newest version
```

As you see it says **isc-dhcp-server** is the newer version. and that one will install. So the reason which your command is **not** run is: you start that by `dhcp3-server`

Comment: service isc-dhcp-server restart [FAIL] Stopping ISC DHCP server: dhcpd failed! [FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed! failed! then dhcp3-server replace by isc-dhcp-server ? yeah ? and if i want to use it i must type isc-dhcp-server ? i test it ; this command not found too –

Comment: this is answer tanx everybody

Comment: @Bahram, If this answer solved your question, Check its accept flag. See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers